# I want to Bind this 2 monthly tax table

Tags: sql-server

I have an example SQL table which has invoice details (Total amount , date exc..). I want to make a SQL View using this invoice table. This view has to include MyInvoiceTax and CustomerInvoiceTax and month parameters.Also if one of this 2 column (MyInvoiceTax and CustomerInvoiceTax) has 0 value, I need to write zero. That calculations should be done by month. FaturaTuru is defining which invoice is mine (1 = sales , 0= goings ).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvvAt.png)

```
Select SUM(KdvTutari) as MyIncoiceTax , DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih) as Month from TumFaturaTbl where  FaturaTuru=1 Group By DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih)

Select SUM(KdvTutari) as CustomerInvoiceTax , DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih) as Month from TumFaturaTbl where  FaturaTuru=0 Group By DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih)
```

I`ve tried bind with nested select query. But it didn't work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation Sum(Case...)
.

```
SELECT SUM(case when FaturaTuru=1 then KdvTutari else 0 end) as MyIncoiceTax, 
       SUM(case when FaturaTuru=0 then KdvTutari else 0 end) as CustomerInvoiceTax, 
       DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih) as Month 
FROM TumFaturaTbl 
WHERE FaturaTuru in (1,0) 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,TumFaturaTbl.Tarih)
--ORDER by month(TumFaturaTbl.Tarih) ASC
```

Caution should be warranted if you're just grouping by month, you will get multiple years in a given month unless yo have year limits somehow....

Alternatively one could use a pivot function...  Though I generally I try and avoid presentation aspects in SQL.

Comment: Hi. thx for your answer. It`is working great but I need to use a month for once.I mean if april has value for MyInvoiceTax  it has to be in same row with CustomerInvoiceTax in april . Your solution`s export like this : https://i.hizliresim.com/c1akj7h.PNG

Comment: remove `FaturaTuru` from the `group by`  oversight on my part from.